# Java Switch Case return type

Tags: java

Hi I have a Switch case like

```
@Override
public <RERURN_TYPE...???> convert(Object argToken, Object argFieldToken) {
    Object obj = Precondition.ensureNotNull(argToken, "Input Object");
    Field field = (Field) Precondition
            .ensureNotNull(argFieldToken, "Field");

    Type type = Type.valueOf(field.getType().getName());
    switch (type) {
    case BYTE:
        break;
    case SHORT:
        break;
    case INTEGER:
        return Integer.parseInt(argToken.toString());
        break;
    case LONG:
        break;
    case FLOAT:
        break;
    case DOUBLE:
        break;
    case CHARACTER:
        break;
    case BOOLEAN:
        break;
    case STRING:
        break;
    case BIGINT:
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here I am converting the "argToken" value depends on the type of the field. Finally the return value will change according to that field type. So how can I maintain the return type which accepts all the return types.

Can anyone please explain this. I stuck over here...
Please...

Amar

Comment: You can't do something like that.  Your return type will have to be `Object`.

Comment: "maintain the return type which accepts all the return types"       Not Possible if i am getting what you want

Answer (score 1):

You could design the switch part a lot easier like that:

```
if(argToken instanceof Integer) {
    return (int) argToken;
} else if(/* some other types */) {
    //cast and return the other types
} else {
    return null;
}
```

But this would only work with the return type `Object`. The only alternative would be to write methods for each primitive type.

So there is no real solution.